# Remove unwanted text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react building an ecommerce. I am getting data from API and setting is as dangerouslySetInnerHTML into JSX. I need to remove some text/word from the API data. I added a picture with mark.

How do I remove that?

```
with(document)with(body)with(insertBefore(createElement("script"),firstChild))setAttribute("exparams","userid=&aplus&ali_beacon_id=&ali_apache_id=&ali_apache_track=&ali_apache_tracktmp=&dmtrack_c={}&hn=aeproductsourcesite033001217071%2eus44&asid=AQAAAADkyhRi8NcdZwAAAABHROT4NDi+yA==&sidx=Fzc+BeTKFGIAAAAA0uvd1jNUkicntMPM",id="beacon-aplus",src="//assets.alicdn.com/g/alilog/??aplus_plugin_aefront/index.js,mlog/aplus_v2.js")

Package included:1 Dress
Material:100% Cotton
Colors:Beige,Navy,Light Green,Pink
Size:S,M,L,XL,2XL,,,
Sleeve Length:Full Sleeve
Neckline:Square Neck
Pattern: Solid Color
Length:Ankle Length
Thickness:Thin
Decoration:Side Pockets
Style:Leisure,Bohemian,Retro,Europe
Season:Spring,Summer,Autumn
Occasion:Family,Holiday,Employment,Travel
```

I need to remove first part of text:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqEQd.jpg)

Picture: https://prnt.sc/RNl4TG6habCe

Comment: Please don't add images, add the code and the expected output, directly

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode posting code instead of images will ease people here to help you resolve your problem.

Comment: Also be clearer in your questions, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why does this api returns JavaScript code instead of json for example?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it's coming from another source like scrapping data.

Answer (score 0):

One options is that you can use regex with either the `split()` method, or using the `match()` method instead. The regular expression will vary based on the method you choose to use.

```js
const data = `with(document)with(body)with(insertBefore(createElement("script"),firstChild))setAttribute("exparams","userid=&aplus&ali_beacon_id=&ali_apache_id=&ali_apache_track=&ali_apache_tracktmp=&dmtrack_c={}&hn=aeproductsourcesite033001217071%2eus44&asid=AQAAAADkyhRi8NcdZwAAAABHROT4NDi+yA==&sidx=Fzc+BeTKFGIAAAAA0uvd1jNUkicntMPM",id="beacon-aplus",src="//assets.alicdn.com/g/alilog/??aplus_plugin_aefront/index.js,mlog/aplus_v2.js")

Package included:1 Dress
Material:100% Cotton
Colors:Beige,Navy,Light Green,Pink
Size:S,M,L,XL,2XL,,,
Sleeve Length:Full Sleeve
Neckline:Square Neck
Pattern: Solid Color
Length:Ankle Length
Thickness:Thin
Decoration:Side Pockets
Style:Leisure,Bohemian,Retro,Europe
Season:Spring,Summer,Autumn
Occasion:Family,Holiday,Employment,Travel`;

const removeWithSplit = (data) => data.split(/(\n|\r){2,}/).pop();

const removeWithMatch = (data) => data.match(/(\w\s?)+:.*/g)?.join('\n');

console.log('**WITH SPLIT**');
console.log(removeWithSplit(data), '\n');

console.log('**WITH MATCH**');
console.log(removeWithMatch(data), '\n');
```

**Bonus:**

It's a bummer the API returns this plain text. Is it possible to get JSON back instead? If not, here's a way to convert its results into an object:

```
const data = `with(document)with(body)with(insertBefore(createElement("script"),firstChild))setAttribute("exparams","userid=&aplus&ali_beacon_id=&ali_apache_id=&ali_apache_track=&ali_apache_tracktmp=&dmtrack_c={}&hn=aeproductsourcesite033001217071%2eus44&asid=AQAAAADkyhRi8NcdZwAAAABHROT4NDi+yA==&sidx=Fzc+BeTKFGIAAAAA0uvd1jNUkicntMPM",id="beacon-aplus",src="//assets.alicdn.com/g/alilog/??aplus_plugin_aefront/index.js,mlog/aplus_v2.js")

Package included:1 Dress
Material:100% Cotton
Colors:Beige,Navy,Light Green,Pink
Size:S,M,L,XL,2XL,,,
Sleeve Length:Full Sleeve
Neckline:Square Neck
Pattern: Solid Color
Length:Ankle Length
Thickness:Thin
Decoration:Side Pockets
Style:Leisure,Bohemian,Retro,Europe
Season:Spring,Summer,Autumn
Occasion:Family,Holiday,Employment,Travel`;

const removeWithMatch = (data: string) => data.match(/(\w\s?)+:.*/g)?.join('\n');

const resultsToObject = (data: string) => {
    return data.split('\n').reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const [key, value] = curr.split(':');

        return {
            ...acc,
            [key]: value,
        };
    }, {} as Record<string, unknown>);
};

console.log(resultsToObject(removeWithMatch(data) as string));
```

Comment: Thanks. I've no controll over the API response it's coming from external source something like scrapping.

Comment: @EbnSina That's a bummer. I'm surprised the scraping software hasn't been configured to output JSON.